# How do I troubleshoot an html email template if I don't see the error the customer does?

Tags: html, email, templates, outlook

I am trying to troubleshoot an email template that one of our customers said doesn't work on Outlook 10. Now I'm very familiar with how horrendous coding for Outlook is, but that's not  really the problem. The issue is that we use Email on Acid for our testing, and everything appears to be fine and dandy over there on all available clients for mobile, desktop and web.

Apart from coding blind and using the customer as refresh (ugh), does anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: I used this: https://help.campaignmonitor.com/test-your-email-campaigns-before-sending

Comment: Thanks James, I checked it out and I don't think that'll do it, I'm looking for a more "testing" oriented service/platform or any ideas. :-)

Comment: I have experienced different Outlook **sub-versions** cause issues with VML. If the customer is able to send screenshot of the issue and you provide the code maybe someone can have a look.

Comment: Tools like Litmus or Email on Acid can show you how an email looks on various flavors of Outlook (2007, 2010) or Gmail, but are only running one version of the email client. Most services run the latest build, but if your client has an older build, it might account for why it looks fine when you build it and bad when the client sees it.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I hadn't thought about the sub-versions/older builds, that's a good point. The customer did send me a screenshot (after my initial post here), the email is much narrower than it should be and the columns behave in a weird way. Unfortunately I can't provide the code since it's not open source and I'm a freelancer, that would go badly for me :-( 
I might have to just use the customer as refresh - or try to find a workaround from inside the platform.
Thanks guys